# How to delete blank lines in chart line in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart, linechart

I want to delete the horizontal lines that appear in a chart line as values, but I can´t find the correct option in properties of the chart:

[image: chart line with blank lines]

I want the chart to look like this instead:

[image: Chart line without blank lines]

Answer (score 2):

The JasperReports chart element model does not expose that attribute.  You'll need to write a chart customizer (or theme) so set it.

The customizer class would look like this:

```
package my.code;

import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRAbstractChartCustomizer;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRChart;

public class LineChartCustomizer extends JRAbstractChartCustomizer
{
    @Override
    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart)
    {
        CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
        plot.setRangeGridlinesVisible(false);
    }
}
```

You would then need to set the customizer class for the chart element:

```
        <lineChart>
            <chart customizerClass="my.code.LineChartCustomizer">
            ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I`m using Jasperreport 6.5.1.